# PDE separation of variables $u_{xx} = X''(x)T(t)$ for imaginary $\lambda$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, solution-verification

#### Relevant information

Given a separation of a PDE
$$ u_{xx} = X''(x) T(t), \tag{1}$$
with
$$ T'(t)=-k \lambda^2 T(t),\tag{2a}$$
and
$$ X''(x)=-\lambda^2 X(x) \tag{2b}$$

#### Problem statement

We consider a case for $\lambda^2 < 0$ (so $\lambda$ is imaginary). Write down $u_{xx}$ from $(1)$ for this choice of $\lambda$ , and solve the ODEs to show that general solution have the form $u(x,t) = e^{-k\lambda^2 t} (Ae^{\lvert \lambda \rvert x} + Be^{-\lvert \lambda \rvert x})$, where $A$ , $B$ are arbitrary constants.

#### Attempt at solution

Since $\lambda^2 < 0 $ then $(2\text{a})$ becomes
\begin{gather}
T'(t) = \lambda^2 k T(t) 
\implies \ln \lvert T(t)\rvert = \lambda^2 k t 
\implies T(t) = e^{\lambda^2kt}
\end{gather}
Then additionally, $(2\text{b})$ becomes
\begin{gather}
X''(x) = \lambda^2 X(x) \implies X(x) = \pm \lambda
\end{gather}
Therefore the solution to $(2\text{b})$ is
\begin{align}
&X(x) = Ae^{\lambda x} + Be^{-\lambda x} \\
\implies &X''(x) = \lambda^2 (Ae^{\lambda x} + Be^{-\lambda x})
\end{align}
Substituting everything back in $(1)$ we get
$$ u_{xx}= \lambda^2 e^{\lambda^2 kt}(Ae^{\lambda t} + Be^{-\lambda t}).$$

#### Conclusion and questions

This result does not match what I was initially looking for. Particularly, I'm missing a minus sign on the term $e^{\lambda^2 k t}$. Moreover, I don't understand why we take the modulus (or absolute value) of $\lambda$ in the general solution of $(2\text{b})$, is it a convention that the square root of a complex number involves its modulus somehow ? Finally I have an extra $\lambda^2$ term but I imagine this is just a constant that I can take out since it may be embedded in the arbitrary constants $A$ and $B$ ?

Comment: In your "Attempt at a solution section," in the sentence that begins "Then, additionally, (2b) becomes" you write the equation (2b) but without a minus sign. That's where you forgot it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I though that since $\lambda^2 <0$ then I have to remove the minus sign but now I understand my mistake. But I still get $X(x) = \pm i \lambda$ for the roots of $(2\text{b})$ and in the final solution that I'm seeking there is involved a modulus , do you know where that comes from ?

Comment: Since $\lambda$ is itself imaginary, $\pm i\lambda = \pm|\lambda|$.

Comment: Interesting, is that like a known fact or something? Because when I went through I saw that if $\lambda = a+ib$ then $i(a+ib) = ai-b$ but $\lvert \lambda \rvert  = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$. Is $ai-b = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ somehow ? Thank you again for helping

Comment: I said imaginary, not complex. That is, $\lambda=bi$ has zero real part.

Comment: Oh my god, I was interchanging the meanings of imaginary and complex for all this time ! Thank you so much :) !